# SQL Weighted Average - Population & Income

Tags: sql, netezza

I am trying to find the average household income while using a weighted average. I have a data source of ZIP codes with the total population and the average household income. I want to be able to select multiple ZIP codes and still pull an accurate average household income.

Can I use SQL to pull a weighted average like this?

| ZIP | TOTAL_POP | AVG_HH_INC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 130350 | 66000 |
| 54321 | 55750 | 78000 |
| 44668 | 17300 | 89000 |

Answer (score 1):

If you want the overall average, then use arithmetic:

```
select sum(total_pop * avg_hh_inc) / sunm(total_pop)
from t;
```

Note:  If the values are stored as 4-byte integers, then this runs the risk of overflow.  Just use a different numeric representation if that is an issue.